# Display more columns from the db in the DropDownList

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, sqldatasource

How can I display two columns in the DropDownList in asp.net?

```
SqlDataSourceNamePeop.SelectCommand = "select name,forename from people";
DropDownListCaptain.DataTextField = "name";
```

Like this it displays only the names. But how can i display the names+forenames?

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListPeople" 
                  runat="server" 
                  DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceNamePeop">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceNamePeop" 
                   ConnectionString="xxxxx" 
                   runat="server">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: please, tell us more about the tools, frameworks, technologies, back-end tools that you are using, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to make your sql query like this:

```
SqlDataSourceNameJuc.SelectCommand = "select name + ' ' +forename as FullName from people";
```

then bind this custom property to your drop down list like this:

```
DropDownListCaptain.DataTextField = "FullName";
```

Let me know if it fixed your problem, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Change your select command to

```
"Select name + ',' + forename as 'name' from people"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList9" runat="server" 
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" DataTextField="**CALL_NAMESURNAME**" 
            DataValueField="CALL_NAME">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:McCarthyConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT [CALL_NAME], [SURNAME],**CALL_NAME + SURNAME AS [CALL_NAMESURNAME]** FROM [Sheet1$] where COY_NAME LIKE '%abc%'">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

CHECK THE ** ** PARTS

Answer (score 0):

```
IList<PM_ClientInformation> objPM_ClientInformation = new List<PM_ClientInformation>();

//get information in objPM_ClientInformation 

            foreach (PM_ClientInformation f in objPM_ClientInformation)
            {
                string text = string.Format("{0}{1}",
                    f.PM_cliFirstName.PadRight(10,'\u00A0'),
                    f.PM_cliLastName.PadRight(10,'\u00A0'));
                ddlClientName.Items.Add(new ListItem (text ,f.PM_cliId.ToString()));
            }
```

it defiantly work.

Answer (score -1):

Dropdownlist cannot display two items. you have to merge trhem and then bind the result to it.

note that there are some other dropdownlist (ajax based or simple ) which are able to bind to two or more columns, but ASP.net is not able to cope with it