# ASP.NET How to display 2 column in dropdownlist?

Tags: asp.net

I use dropdownlist with SQLDataSource to add on dropdownlist. Since there is only 1 DataTextField to display, how can i add second one to it? I want to display description and workprocess on the list, here HTML code,

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownWorkProcess" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Description" DataValueField="WorkProcess">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Database_Shared_NotebookConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Description], [WorkProcess] as workprocess FROM [tblWorkProcess]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

If that cannot work, is there other easier simple way from 3rd party such as AJAX Toolkit?

Comment: Telerik has a good combo box which will give a neat dropdown.http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display more columns from the db in the DropDownList](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315530/display-more-columns-from-the-db-in-the-dropdownlist)

Answer (score 1):

Try concatenating the fields :

```
SELECT [Description] + ' ' + [WorkProcess] as workprocess FROM [tblWorkProcess]
```

Comment: this doesn't work, I got error result, DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'WorkProcess'.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a dropdown list to achieve this sort of thing since DropDown lists are rendered on the browser as `select` elements.

You need to use a custom control. People typically use unordered lists (`ul`) and list items (`li`) to achieve the behaviour you want.

Telerik controls use that approach - ul and li. See here: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/functionality/multicolumncombo/defaultcs.aspx